# QT Webkit with DirectFB

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I have QT 5.5 & QTWebkit and am trying to bring it up on i686 platform.
 Everything builds fine , but QTWebkit seems to be configured by default with eglfs. It always try to load egfs plugin instead of directfb.

I tried with the below configuration,
In ./configure -directfb -no-eglfs -no-opengl respectively. It does not generate eglfs plugin, Now i got error saying that there's no eglfs plugin found. How to tell QT to load directfb plugin instead of eglsfs.

Any inputs?
Cheers

Comment: Have you tried reading the doc [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html)? Maybe something to do with environment variables

Comment: Thanks , that worked like a charm.  Setting QT_QPA_PLATFORM to 'directfb' solved the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by setting QT_QPA_PLATFORM to 'directfb'.